# Why is there a potential infinite loop in my JavaScript Code?

Tags: javascript

I wish to find the sum of all prime numbers between range defined from 1 to N.
The code gives an infinite loop when I call the sumPrimes function with a value of 3. I have debugged the code and found out that it does that only for the number 3. It does not do so for any other numbers above 2.

**JavaScript:**

```
function sumPrimes(num) { 
    var sum=0;
    for (i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
        if (checkPrime(i)) {
            sum += i;
        }
    }

    return sum;
}

function checkPrime(num) {
    for (i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i++) {
        if (num % i === 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: How can i be less than 1.73, if it begins at 2?

Comment: There is no infinite loop on 3. However, it won't do anything for 3, as the square root of 3 is less than 2, so it will simply return true. Which is actually correct, as 3 is prime.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado it works for the number 2 though, I am confused as well

Comment: @ManoDestra it is going into infinite loop when 3, i checked it on repl.it and my tab crashes

Comment: Just tested your exact code, prior to my minor edit, on Firefox and it works perfectly. Something else is crashing your code.

Comment: @ManoDestra, fixing the code in the question hides the actual problem.

Comment: I'm still confused... I'm not seeing any infinite loop there!

Comment: Yes, apologies. My error. It was unclear from the question that the problem actually lay in sumPrimes (overwriting the global i), rather than checkPrime.

Comment: @ManoDestra is it browser related or is it just an obvious problem?

Comment: @PranavGhate No, your sumPrimes does have an infinite loop in it, as you were declaring `i` globally, rather than locally. All you need to do is add `var` prior to your `i` in your for loops. Always use var in a for loop declaration. e.g. `for (var i = 0; i < someValue; i++) {`

Comment: holy hell thanks guys, it was the absence of 'var'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have to declare `i` with `var` : it will make it local to the function.

```
for (var i = 2; i <= num...
```

otherwise the two functions use the same global variable.

If you want to avoid this kind of bug, you should use `strict mode`.
[JavaScript Use Strict](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp)

You just have to put `"use strict";` at the top of your .js file.

Comment: And would you then please explain *why* that omission (which occurs in two places in the posted code) would produce "an obviously very-subtle bug?" It does not matter that the variable is used within the body of a function? Interesting ... *(And yet-another reason why I long ago stopped writing source-code directly in JavaScript ...!)*

Comment: Doesnt matter if var is used or not

Comment: It does matter. You need to add var prior to i in both functions above.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't declared a scope for `i`, which means that both loops will keep resetting the value of `i` in global scope, causing the loop to continue endlessly.

Add `var i` to the top of both functions and the problem will disappear.